# Bootstrap how to get the navbar not to be fixed

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys i am trying to create a website with bootstrap for the first time and trying to sort out the basic layout. However I am having two problems right now.

First, my main body which I have colored in white is not in the middle of the page. 
I am trying to make the main page look something like this :

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|    |                          |              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |Logo               Nav Bar|              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |                           |             |
|    |                           |             |
|    |      Body                 |             |
|    |                           |             |
|    |                           |             |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |Logo          Info        |              |
|-----------------------------------------------                        
|    |                          |              |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

However for some reason the body is stuck to the left and not in the middle.

The biggest problem i have got is my nabar. Because i have my body which is very high and requires you to scroll, it means that when i scroll the nav bar will overlap the white body and this is a big problem

Any help on this would be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainHome">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>





.mainHome {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 1600px;
    width: 500px;
    div.align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Your class on navbar : `navbar-fixed-top`, why that if you do not want this behavior ?

Comment: i was following a tutorial ,  i am not sure how to make it movable

Comment: @Nevershow2016 You need to edit your post so that the HTML code shows up. I think you just need to add a new line after 'HTML'. And then maybe add a 'CSS' headline before the CSS bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">`

The "navbar-fixed-top" means what ie means. That your navbar will have a CSS fixed position on screen. ie it will still be there when you scroll

> `<div class="container">`

Containers in bootstrap are of two types : the standard container is the one used for responsive design of fixed sized, whereas liquid layouts are the ones that stretch infinitely

I suggest that you use only one container for everything, unless you want a "header bar" that stretches infinitely (use liquid layout/container-fluid).

Also I am wondering, if you are following a tutorial, why do you use so much extra CSS instead of just using bootstrap sylesheets ? That is killing the point of bootstrap. Why would you have fixed width for your mainHome (which I assume is what you called "body" on your graph) when bootstrap is supposed to handle that ?

I have serious doubts about your tutorial.

So

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="mainHome"></div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i am a bit confused what u mean about the body. I put the body in as the .mainHome however the problem is it ends up on the left hand side and not int he middle of the screen like it should be, this is why i have had to add css